# How a servlet can read array list through the request header?

Tags: servlets

I tried to send a url which contains `http://192.168.1.xxx:8080/AttendanceTrack/UserGroupController?usersList=arrayList`
where usersList is the parameter name of an ArrayList.

In the servlet side, I tried to access as follows

```
ArrayList usersList = (ArrayList) request.getAttribute("usersList");
```

But I got only null value.

Answer (score 0):

In my client side, I changed my code as

```
String json = new Gson().toJson(arrayList);
jsonObject.put("usersList", json);
```

and appended the parameter name in url and send it to the server side.

In my server side,

```
String jsonString = request.getParameter("usersList");
```

Problem is fixed.